# Convergence test for this function?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have the series:

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^∞ \sqrt{n+1}$$

- I tried using the Comparison test, but I'm not sure what to compare it to.
- I can't use the Integral Test because it's not a decreasing function.
- The Ratio Test yields $\infty/\infty$, and I wasn't sure if this equals $\infty$ or not

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do the terms tend to $0$?

Comment: No, they don't. They get infinitely bigger. I know the series is divergent, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: One of the standard tests is that if the terms don't go to zero, the series diverges.

Comment: My teacher wants me to use one of the three tests that I listed above, so I don't know if he'll accept that as an answer.

Comment: Compare to the known diverging series $\sum_{n \ge 0} 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sqrt{n+1} \geq \sum_{n=0}^\infty 1 = +\infty$. So:

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sqrt{n+1} = +\infty$ and it diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Notice

$$ \lim \sqrt{n+1} \neq 0 $$

Hence, $\sum \sqrt{n+1} $ must be divergent by the limit criterion.

Answer (score 0):

Using the comparison test:
For every $n$, you have $n+1>1$, therefore $\sqrt{n+1} > 1$, meaning that each element in the sum is larger than $1$, so your sum diverges because $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1$$ diverges.